# Magento 2.3 Error on Delete All Test Data from Database

Tags: database, magento2.3, foreign-key, foreign-key-constraint

We are in the process of migrating to Magento 2.3, but need to remove all test data from the database and reset all increment ID's back to 1.  Having some troubles removing all order information:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

TRUNCATE TABLE `gift_message`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_address`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_address_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_id_mask`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_item_option`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_payment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_shipping_rate`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `reporting_orders`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_daily`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_monthly`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_creditmemo`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_creditmemo_comment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_creditmemo_grid`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_creditmemo_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoice`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoiced_aggregated`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoiced_aggregated_order`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoice_comment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoice_grid`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoice_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_address`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_aggregated_created`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_aggregated_updated`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_grid`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_payment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_status_history`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_tax`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_tax_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_payment_transaction`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_refunded_aggregated`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_refunded_aggregated_order`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment_comment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment_grid`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment_track`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipping_aggregated`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipping_aggregated_order`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `tax_order_aggregated_created`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `tax_order_aggregated_updated`;

ALTER TABLE `sales_order` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Produces the following SQL Error:

> TRUNCATE TABLE `quote`
>
> Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint (`m2`.`quote_address`, CONSTRAINT `QUOTE_ADDRESS_QUOTE_ID_QUOTE_ENTITY_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`quote_id`) REFERENCES `m2`.`quote` (`entity_id`))

Comment: where do you run your SQL query? on a cli or PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: Running from PHPMyAdmin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was checking your SQL query and there seems to be no error or mistake on it, it should work on a MySQL CLI but having said that, the only thing I can assume is:

> you run your SQL query on a **phpMyadmin SQL interface** with the **Enable foreign key checks** **checked.** Usually, it is found at the lower right of the SQL query interface.
>   Try to **uncheck it** and your query should work.

Note: In order to reset the Order number, you have to include this in your query, **TRUNCATE TABLE sequence_order_1** — this table is responsible for generating the **increment_id** or the **order number** on the frontend.

Hope that helps!

Comment: This fixed it! I wasn't unchecking Foregn Key Checks, also thanks for the tip on the sequence_order_1, I missed that as well.  Cheers!