# Magento 2 - Order ID always ZERO

Tags: sales-order, sequence

When I click "Place Order" the order ID is always 0 and therefore fails after the first order as the order id already exists.
TABLE SEQUENCE_ORDER_1 gets 0 appended to it
I have no idea why and I've spent ages tracking through all the files that deal with the sales sequence and got nowhere.

Does anyone have an idea?
Where does ORDER ID first get assigned?

> main.CRITICAL: Saving order 000000000 failed: Unique constraint
>   violation found [] []

Comment: are you starting out? try this one it might help you https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/264099/magento-2-3-error-on-delete-all-test-data-from-database/264194#264194

Answer (score 0):

I've sorted it.

Somehow the primary key had got lost which meant auto_increment had also got lost.